# Add null in duplicate column in SQL 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL 2014.I wrote a stored procedure for generating a report,But i need to avoid the duplicate values in a particular column.

My sql query output is as follows:

```
Column1  Column2  Column3
-----------------------------
A          100       test1
A          200       test2
B          150       test5
B          180       test4
B          25        test5
```

I need to add Null or blank in place of duplicate column values in Column1

```
Column1  Column2  Column3
-----------------------------
A          100       test1
           200       test2
B          150       test5
           180       test4
           25        test5
```

How can I do this,Any Help?

Comment: Fix it in the presentation layer.

Comment: This you can achieve in your report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1
    ([Column1] varchar(1), [Column2] int, [Column3] varchar(5))
;

INSERT INTO #Table1
    ([Column1], [Column2], [Column3])
VALUES
    ('A', 100, 'test1'),
    ('A', 200, 'test2'),
    ('B', 150, 'test5'),
    ('B', 180, 'test4'),
    ('B', 25, 'test5')
;

with cte as 
(
select *,row_number() over (partition by [Column1] order by [Column1]) as  r from #Table1
)

update cte
set column1=''
 where r>1

output

Column1 Column2 Column3
A       100     test1
        200     test2
B       150     test5
        180     test4
         25     test5
```